# Slow Line drawing in GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm completely new to Winforms and GDI+, I come from a WPF background. Using the simple code below to draw 1000 Lines I noticed that it doesn't draw the Lines at once like WPF does. It is slow and the process of drawing is actually noticable. Am I missing something in the code below?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g;
    g = CreateGraphics();

    var pn = new Pen(Color.Wheat, 1);
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var n = 0;

    while (n < 1000)
    {
        x = x + 5;
        if (x > 1200)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = y + 15;
        }
        g.DrawLine(pn, x, y, x, y + 10);

        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Override the onDraw method,  inside this method You can recieive the canvas and draw onto it, using only one handle, afaik. So Your button can just set something like a counter or flag and call invalidate, and in the onDraw eventhandler You then can draw fast.

Comment: I've done a simple test in both WPF and WinForms, in WPF it takes 36ms to generate your above code, in WinForms only 10 so at some point on your end something is going wrong.

Comment: Did you do it using the exact code above in GDI+? I'm actually seeing the lines being drawn.

Comment: I've created a small solution to compare the drawing speed, you can try it yourself on your own machine. [Link to solution](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19090714/DrawingComparison.7z)